# Vagrant up fails with loading plugin

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, vagrantfile, vagrant-plugin, zulip

The zulip setup requires having Vagrant setup.
https://github.com/zulip/zulip
But it fails in Ubuntu 14.04

```
$vagrant plugin install vagrant-lxc
Installing the 'vagrant-lxc' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Installed the plugin 'vagrant-lxc (1.2.1)'!


$vagrant up
Failed to load the "vagrant-lxc" plugin. View logs for more details.
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:
vm:
* The box 'ubuntu/trusty64' could not be found.
```

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem do not seem to come from the plugin but from the box instead.

can you download the box using `vagrant box add ubuntu/trusty64 https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64`

once the box is installed, you should be able to run `vagrant up`

Also why would you need `vagrant-lxc` plugin if you're running on normal ubuntu box, did you mean to use another box ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My ubuntu box had vagrant 1.4.3, I upgraded to 1.7.4. After the upgrade, it worked fine.